# React history in constructor and in componentdidMount is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I have a top App component and child LoginForm component. App component send this.history to loginform props and loginForm call history.pust('/') on successful login
But if I need to call this.history in App constructor or in comonentDidMount it is undefined. I dont understand ho is it possible. Can somebody help me please to understand it?

```
import React from "react"
import {
    Switch,
    Route,
    NavLink
} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./components/Home"
import Topics from "./components/Topics"
import Login from "./components/Login"
import About from "./components/About"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './assets/App.scss';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'
window.$ = require('jquery')
require('popper.js')
require('bootstrap')


class App extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            accessToken: this.getAccessToken()
        }

        if( ! this.state.accessToken ) this.history.push('/login')  // Error call push of undefined 
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        console.log(this.history)  // undefined <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="container-fluid content">
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact>
                                <Home />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path="/login">
                                <Login history={this.history} />  // This is ok <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                            </Route>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are you using react-router-Dom?

Comment: I'm not sure what `this.history` is...usually you can get the global `window.history`, or you can get `props.history` from a component that is within the `Router`...what is `this.history?`  I don't see it defined anywhere on your component

Comment: @Shimili Breuer yes I am using react-route-Dom

Comment: @Seth Lutske it is router history object not window.history

Comment: That's what i figured. when trying to access the router history, you access is as a prop.  as in `this.props.history`, not `this.history`.  Or `props.history` for a functional component.  And keep in mind that its only available to you for components that are wrapped in the router.  So I'm assuming your `App` component is wrapped in `<Router>`.

Comment: Yes whole app it is wrapped in the router. So `<Login history={this.history} />` this object in this line is Router not App? I thought it is the same this like in other place in App.